# How to change display date and tick with pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a graph that looks like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dGru.jpg)

And I need the x axis to display all days in %d/%m/%Y format without the hours displayed and not the dates every 4 days like this.

Just like this (without the hour):

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMnKx.png)

Here is my (terrible) code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms

a_file = open("a.txt", "r", encoding='utf8',errors='replace')
y_data = a_file.readlines()[-150:]

# sorting the y data so I can find the lowest and uppest values for the graph
min_servs = 0
max_servs = 0
x1 = []
y1 = []
sort1 = []
for line in y_data:
    before, sep, after = line.partition(' | ')
    before1, sep1, after1 = after.partition('.')
    after = before1
    x1.append(before)
    y1.append(float(int(after.replace(".0",""))))
    sort1.append(float(int(after.replace(".0",""))))

x = []
y = []
sort = []
x = x1
for items in y1:
    before2, sep2, after2 = str(items).replace(".0","").partition('.')
    item = str(before2).replace("[","").replace("]","")
    y.append(int(before2))
for items in sort1:
    before2, sep2, after2 = str(items).replace(".0","").partition('.')
    item = str(before2).replace("[","").replace("]","")
    sort.append(int(before2))
sort.sort()

# get all the differents days
days_list = []
for item in x:
    before_, sep_, after_ = item.partition(' ')
    if not before_ in days_list:
        days_list.append(before_)

before2, sep2, after2 = str(sort[:1]).replace(".0","").partition('.')
min_servs = str(before2).replace("[","").replace("]","") # oh my god no way i coded this lmao
min_servs = int(min_servs) - 1 # -1 and +1 so the lines didnt touch the border of the graph

before2, sep2, after2 = str(sort[-1]).replace(".0","").partition('.')
max_servs = str(before2).replace("[","").replace("]","") # i'm sorry
max_servs = int(max_servs) + 1


#finally the pandas thing

x = pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

DF = pd.DataFrame()
DF['value'] = y
DF = DF.set_index(x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#ticks
ax.scatter(x=x, y=y)
ytick = range(min_servs, max_servs)
xtick = days_list # I don't understand how it works
ax.set_yticks(ytick)
ax.set_xticks(ytick)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()


plt.figure(figsize=(15,10), dpi=50)
base = plt.gca().transData
rot = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(90)
plt.grid(visible=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(visible=True, which='minor', color='#999999', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
plt.plot(x, y, color="#0000ff", linestyle='-', linewidth = 3, marker='o', markerfacecolor="#0000ff", markersize=8)


# setting x and y axis range 

date_min = x[:1]
date_max = x[-1]


plt.ylim(min_servs, max_servs)
plt.xlim(date_min, date_max)

plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=24) 
plt.ylabel('Serveurs', fontsize=24) 
plt.title('Graphique des serveurs', fontsize=28)

plt.show()
```

a.txt:

```
18/08/2022 21:05:00 | 240
18/08/2022 21:54:00 | 241
18/08/2022 21:55:00 | 240
19/08/2022 22:06:00 | 241
19/08/2022 22:27:00 | 240
20/08/2022 02:49:00 | 241
20/08/2022 02:55:00 | 242
20/08/2022 14:38:00 | 243
20/08/2022 15:01:00 | 242
```

I don't want to modify the data so as not to change the graph but I would just like to change the data displayed below the graph.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your code doesn't work ... provide a minimal code illustrating the problem you have.

Comment: It's a good idea not to use `sort` as a variable name for a list.

Comment: I just fixed it @Claudio

Comment: so provide an answer yourself with the fix ( but consider also to delete your question, because I can't see any benefit from it for its future visitors ).

Comment: no I mean my code was not working at all my fault but now it is but I still haven't fixed my problem. @Claudio

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).